# Remove list from a list in C# based on specific condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to remove objects of one list that are present on other list according to condition here are my two lists

List Structure

```
list1 = {GuideId ,Text , Desc , SecId , NextBtnText , ParentId}

list2 = {userId , ParentId , GuideId , Status }
```

data for list one

```
list1[0]{GuideId = 1 , Text=abc , Desc=any , SecId =2 , ParentId = 2}

list1[1]{GuideId = 2 , Text=abc , Desc=any , SecId =2 , ParentId = 2}

list1[2]{GuideId = 3 , Text=abc , Desc=any , SecId =2 , ParentId = 2}

list1[3]{GuideId = 4 , Text=abc , Desc=any , SecId =2 , ParentId = 2}

list1[4]{GuideId = 5 , Text=abc , Desc=any , SecId =2 , ParentId = 2}
```

data for list 2

```
list2[0]{GuideId = 1 , Text=abc , Desc=any , SecId =2 , ParentId = 2}

list2[1]{GuideId = 2 , Text=abc , Desc=any , SecId =2 , ParentId = 2}

list2[2]{GuideId = 3 , Text=abc , Desc=any , SecId =2 , ParentId = 2}
```

these data come from db it may be thousand

but I need where GuideId matches it would remove the data from list

what I applied is not working

Here is the code

```
List1 = List1.Except(List2).ToList();
```

Here is my Code

```
  userGuideList = query.ToList<GuidedPopupsViewModel>();
     popUpGuideListVm = query2.ToList<GuidedPopupsViewModel>();
    popUpGuideListVm = popUpGuideListVm.Except(userGuideList).ToList();
```

Comment: I don't get any result

Comment: This looks like pseudo code... what have you tried so far?

Comment: What kind of database are you using?

Comment: And just to clarify, you need to remove a row of data if the `GuedeId` matches your condition?

Comment: What are `userGuedeList`, and `popUpGuedeListVm`?  As in, is it a string, object, array, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That doesn't work because `Except` doesn't know how you want to compare the objects. So it just compares references. You have to override `Equals` + `GetHashCode` or you have to provide a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

But you could also use [`List.RemoveAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead:

```
List1.RemoveAll(x=> List2.Any(x2 => x2.GuideId == x.GuideId));
```

Comment: Could you clarify what `List.RemoveAll` is doing in this case?

Comment: can i use the same method for removing all matching rows except parent id

Comment: @KhanEngineer: yes, it would and it does modify the original list without needing to create a new one, so it's relatively efficient. However, when it's large data you should filter in the database instead. If that's not possible create a custom `IEequaliTyComparer<GuidedPopupsViewModel>` and use that for `Except`. That might be more efficient because it's using a set.

Comment: @KhanEngineer: what does that mean, `ParentId` is a property? You mean remove only those where the GuideId matches but the ParentId is different?

Comment: yeah it is property and i want remove data but not parentId because it gives a count of zero when all data matches like list1= 1 ,2,3 and list2=1,2,3 but i don't want the list would be zero

Comment: @khan: how dp you want to remove complete objects without this property? Sorry but thats not clear. What do you want to keep?

Comment: ok leave i want to paste new problem please try to provide the solution

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing based on the GuideId

```
List2.Where(x => !List1.Select(y => y.GuideId).Contains(x.GuideId))
```

Answer (score 0):

another way is using foreach in linq, this one is only comparing ids, no overrides nor reference equality needed:

```
list2.ForEach(x => list.RemoveAll(y => y.GuidId == x.GuidId));
```